# Unable to find the xpath

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am unable to find xpath for the below success message:

```
WebElement successOverlayMsg = findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='A new app overlay \"APAutomation_Merchant_M32XphDFc\" has been created successfully']"));
if (successOverlayMsg.getText().equals("A new app overlay 'APAutomation_Merchant_MUjL7PDwO' has been created successfully"))
```

Comment: It's hard to check your xpath is right or wrong if you don't share the site. But base on your xpath, I'm guessing that it's maybe long text so try: //*[contains(text(),'A new app overlay \"APAutomation_Merchant_M32XphDFc\" has been created successfully')]

Comment: or try xpath with shorter text: //*[contains(text(),'A new app overlay')]

Comment: Did you try explicit wait ? Try the "contains" method and if it  still doesn't work use explicit wait for the text to be present

Comment: And make sure you have only one element that contain the text , else use contains(.,"new overlay") (replace text() with dot)

Comment: Dude you have different endings for string in quotes ;)

Comment: @MichalDobrzycki the element is not located is the main issue ;) but still nice catch